# setting value for particular scope from directive is not working in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have html like this

```
    <div ng-controller="main">
       <div ng-show="showhide">welcome</div>
       <div my-directive>click</div>
       <div ng-click="submit()">submit</div>
    </div>
```

my contoller like this

```
 app.controller('main',function($scope)
{
     $scope.showhide=true;
     $scope.submit=function()
    {

       alert($scope.showhide); //true
       $scope.showhide=true;
    }
});
```

my directive like this

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){

     return function(scope, elem, attrs)
     {
        elem.bind('click', function()
        {
             scope.$apply(function()
             {
               scope.showhide=false;

             });

        });
     }


});
```

my requirement is when i click on click button i have to hide the welcome and then when user click on submit button i have to show but here what happened when i click on click button it is hiding but when i click on submit button it is not showing . in alert also true is coming but false should come so how to solve this? and if you have solution for this explain me that why it is working like this?

give me solution only using this code . please don't change code like using ng-hide instead of ng-show and add more extra div .

Comment: First  of all , try to use `$apply` instead of `apply` : `scope.$apply(...`

Comment: `app.controller('main',function()` should be `app.controller('main',function($scope)`

Comment: yes...i am using $apply  but here i wrote wrongly...

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine if you change the two things already mentioned in the comments:

```
<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="main">
        <div ng-show="showhide">welcome</div>
        <div my-directive>click</div>
        <div ng-click="submit()">submit</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I suspect you're missing declaring your `ng-app`

Updating the code:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('main', function($scope) {
         $scope.showhide=true;
         $scope.submit=function() {

           //alert($scope.showhide); //true
           $scope.showhide=true;
         };
    });

    app.directive('myDirective',function() {

         return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function()
            {
                 scope.$apply(function()
                 {
                   scope.showhide = false;    
                 });    
            });
         }
    });
})();
```

So that you use `$apply` and `$scope`, your code works.

http://jsfiddle.net/6xEBW/

I wrote this fiddle for you.